# TypeError: Input 'b' of 'MatMul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'a'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm trying to follow word2vec example, but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Input 'b' of 'MatMul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'a'.
```

At this line

similarity = tf.matmul(
      tf.cast(valid_embeddings,tf.int32), tf.cast(normalized_embeddings,tf.int32), transpose_b=True)

This is the entire code:

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
  # Input data.
  train_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
  train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
  valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)
  # Ops and variables pinned to the CPU because of missing GPU implementation
  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # Look up embeddings for inputs.
    embeddings = tf.Variable(
        tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)
    # Construct the variables for the NCE loss
    nce_weights = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                            stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
    nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))
  # Compute the average NCE loss for the batch.
  # tf.nce_loss automatically draws a new sample of the negative labels each
  # time we evaluate the loss.
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.nn.nce_loss(nce_weights, nce_biases, embed, train_labels,
                     num_sampled, vocabulary_size))
  # Construct the SGD optimizer using a learning rate of 1.0.
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)
  # Compute the cosine similarity between minibatch examples and all embeddings.
  norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keep_dims=True))
  normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
  valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
      normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
  similarity = tf.matmul(
      tf.cast(valid_embeddings,tf.int32), tf.cast(normalized_embeddings,tf.int32), transpose_b=True)
  # Add variable initializer.
  init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've met the same problem using Tensorflow r1.4 with Python 3.4.

Indeed, I think you need to change the code

```
tf.nn.nce_loss(nce_weights, nce_biases, embed, train_labels,
                 num_sampled, vocabulary_size))
```

into

```
tf.nn.nce_loss(nce_weights, nce_biases, train_labels, embed,
                 num_sampled, vocabulary_size))
```

or

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.nce_loss(
        weights = softmax_weights,
        biases = softmax_biases, 
        inputs = embed, 
        labels = train_labels, 
        num_sampled = num_sampled, 
        num_classes = vocabulary_size))
```

Meanwhile, you need to change the code back to

```
similarity = tf.matmul(valid_embeddings, tf.transpose(normalized_embeddings))
```

It wrong to use `tf.cast(..., tf.int32)` and actually, there is no need to use `tf.cast(..., tf.float32)` because it's already been tf.float32.

p.s.

The solution is also useful when you meet the problem while using `tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss()` because the usage of `sampled_softmax_loss()` is quite similar to `nce_loss()`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing the matrix multiplication in integer space? You probably want both of those tf.cast to be to tf.float32.